# After each batch, the GPU's memory increases

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

After each batch, the GPU's memory increases, eventually leading to an out-of-memory error. I attempted to train the longest data separately, and it can be completed successfully. my batch_size is 1.

if i can train longest data，my batch == 1  how can i train whole dataset

Comment: This is probaly due to an memory leak. Do you save any output of the model or the loss to, let's say a list to calculate statistic later without calling `.detach()`? Another note, if you want other to fix your bug, post the code as well. We are not mind readers.

Comment: I've had a similar problem before, don't quote me but I think it might have had something to do with doing a try/except in my learning loop. [Clearing the GPU's cache](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.empty_cache.html) each iteration might work for you, I remember clearing the cache each iteration helping my issue but not quite resolving it.